# How can I use in a restful way WCF Ria Services?

Tags: wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services

My question is a rephrase of my previous unanswered [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169632/empty-svc-file-using-wcf-ria-services-and-ado-net-data-services) for clarification.
WCF Ria Services is basically a web service (SOAP), exposed via the .svc style web service. How can I reuse my ria domain service (the one containing the CRUD operations) to construct a data service on WCF Data Services?

Thank you and I tried to narrow down my question avoiding duplication.

Comment: You might need to keep clarifying your question because WCF RIA services is a restful service. So I dont understand what you want to do?

Comment: Indeed you are right. I thought that it was a WCF SOAP Web Service and I wanted to have a json endpoint. I didn't know that RIa Services provide that capability:
http://blogs.msdn.com/saurabh/archive/2009/11/23/understanding-the-wcf-in-wcf-ria-services.aspx

Comment: WCF Service works really well with Entity Framework as your data model. These two working together saves a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

In the release we are polishing now, you will be able to simply check a check box (or add a simple config entry) to expose your DomainService as an OData Feed (that is the DataServices wire protocal).  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/12/14/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-json-endpoint-4-5.aspx